# Pug does not replace parameters with values

Tags: node.js, express, pug

The docs of Pug say all the parameters will be replaced with values if they have this form: `#{parameter_name}` This doesn't work for me.

My code:

```
//Template
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        title= title
    body
        h1
            Task is  #{task_id}
        p
            task is #{task_id}
            company is  #{company_id}


//javascript
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
const util = require('util');

app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello World!')
})
app.locals.pretty = true
app.get('/task/:company_id/:task_id',function(req,res) {
    res.render('task',{task_id: req.query.task_id,company_id: req.query.company_id});
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port !')
})
```

And the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      <Task>is  </Task>
    </h1>
    <p>
      <task>is </task>
      <company>is  </company>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

No variable was interpreted!!! What is wrong here? I am following the docs!!! (I am using latest version, installed yesterday)

Comment: I am feeling like those 2 engineers: https://webapplog.com/jade/

Comment: I know this is not the question. Are you sure you want to use Pug? it uses HAML and I dont see you using it correctly, it is whitespace sensitive. I suggest nunjucks which uses HTML https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/

Comment: I really don't care what engine I will be using. Is nunjucks better?

Comment: nunjucks uses HTML which is direct and easy to understand, HAML uses whitespace to decide tags, hence you Tasks has become <tasks> which is not what you want.

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed, I don't know, if I can write in assembly language I guess I can learn pug, but why the hell the variables aren't replaced ???

Comment: assembly? what documentation are you looking at? This is the right doc https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed, i am a C language developer, I don't do much of this interpreted language stuff. Ok, lets go for nunjucks, looks simple enough.

Comment: try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are refering to the query string instead of parameters in your nodejs

Please change your code to this

```
res.render('task',{task_id: req.params.task_id,company_id: req.params.company_id});
```

You need to use params not query

Comment: Welcome. :) Since you are new to this, nunjucks is a better choice. Take care